# FastAPI with redirects on AWS Lambda : Too many redirects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi

I have a Spotify project needing authorization codes through their API. I built an API to redirect the user to Spotify's login and then turn back to my API along with the user's code.

The API:

```
import boto3
import requests
import base64
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from mangum import Mangum
from client import client_id, client_secret

app = APIRouter()
lambda_handler = Mangum(app,lifespan='off')

url = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.lambda-url.me-south-1.on.aws'

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return RedirectResponse("/login/")

@app.get("/home/")
async def main(code: str):
    encoded = base64.b64encode(
        (client_id + ":" + client_secret).encode("ascii")
    ).decode("ascii")

    base = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": f"{url}/home/",
    }

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded,
    }

    tokens = requests.post(base, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
    refresh_token = tokens["refresh_token"]
    access_token = tokens["access_token"]

    email_base_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me"
    email_headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    }

    email = requests.get(email_base_url, headers=email_headers).json()["email"]

    dynamo = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    tokens = dynamo.Table("tokens")
    item = {"email": email, "token": access_token, "refresh_token": refresh_token}
    tokens.put_item(Item=item)

    return {"message": "success"}

@app.get("/login/")
async def login():
    base = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?"
    base += "response_type=code"
    base += f"&client_id={client_id}"
    base += "&scope=user-read-recently-played user-read-email"
    base += f"&redirect_uri={url}/home/"
    return RedirectResponse(base)
```

The API works as intended when I run it on localhost or use an ngrok tunnel. However, when I upload it to AWS Lambda and generate a function URL, the browser returns the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` for any of the three endpoints.

I've seen questions about this topic, but they all included CloudFront. I would be happy to provide information about the Lambda function as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question while trying to resolve my own issue. Wanted to update here in case it helps: just try removing the second forward slash from your endpoint name

Example: Use `@app.get("/login")` instead of `@app.get("/login/")`

This solved it for me! It seems like the second forward slash makes the Lambda function URL get stuck in an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Does it makes a different if you call `baseurl/` vs `baseurl/login` ?

If someone is already logged in and hits the baseurl you redirecting him.

`/` -> `/login` -> `spotify` -> `/home`

You can try sort `/` -> `/login` into one as its still just a redirection.

**Update 1:**

Do not use the same variable `base` in `login` and `main`.

1. Log the urls you are redirecting. This will help you understand what is going on.
2. Urlencode the url before passing it as url param. `base += f"&redirect_uri= {urlencode(url)}/home/"`

Comment: `/` successfully redirects to `/login/`, but after that `/login/` just keeps redirecting onto itself until the browser stops it. Accessing `/login/` directly causes the same recursion loop. For now it seems like the only acceptable endpoint is the root. I tried changing `/login/` to return a json instead of a redirect and it still recurses onto itself. However, changing root to return a json displays the json successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the update, SO didn't notify me about the update. My internet is not stable enough to update the function atm, I will log the URLs and encode the redirect URL as soon as I am able to. I did find a temporary workaround yesterday. I merged both login and home into a single path `/`, so that if `code == None` I call the previously `login` body, else I call the previously `home` body.

Comment: I tried using the `urllib.parse.quote` function on the URL, but it still redirects onto itself. Also, I can't make it print/log the URL to cloudwatch, all I see in cloudwatch are multiple `start, end, and report` pairs, each one containing only the request ID.